# Rango de fechas limitado para input date

Tags: javascript, html, date

Tengo un formulario con un `input` de tipo `date` y quiero que para este mismo no se puedan seleccionar fechas atrasadas al dia actual y fechas adelantadas un par de días.

Tengo este trozo codigo para las fechas atrasadas y funciona correctamente pero no encuentro la forma de hacer uno para las fechas adelantadas

```
const hoy = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', hoy);
```

Si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias, o si no existe forma de hacerlo igualmente.

Answer (score 2):

No está claro en tus requisitos si las fechas probibidas en el futuro son del día segundo en adelante o del día tercero en adelante, pero en todo caso aquí tienes un script que restringe las fechas seleccionables desde el día 3º en adelante, cuyo "constraint" puedes modificar fácilmente para ajustarlo a tus necesidades. Un saludo:

```
const today = new Date();
const minDate = today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
const maxDate = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2))
  .toISOString()
  .split("T")[0];
document.getElementById("date").setAttribute('min', minDate);
document.getElementById("date").setAttribute('max', maxDate);
```

Te he dejado un Codepen donde puedes trastear con el código [aquí](https://codepen.io/alejandromad/pen/gOBGeNz).

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Tomar la fecha actual y sumarle los días que necesites utlizando:

   - [`date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) para obtener el número del día.
   - [`date.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) para cambiar el día
2. Al `input` agregarle el propiedad [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max) (*de igual forma que ya lo haces con `min`*)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const input = document.getElementsByName("date")[0];
const fecha = new Date();

input.setAttribute('min', fecha.toISOString().split("T")[0]);

// A la fecha le sumamos 2 dias
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 2);
input.setAttribute('max', fecha.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date"/>
```